# Find the cube roots of -8i. Express them in algebraic form.

Tags: complex-numbers

Would you do this by translating to trig form and then simplifying?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Yes, polar form should work well.  Actually I can tell by inspection that one of them is $2i$.  Multiply by complex cube roots of unity to get the others

Answer (score 2):

Let $z\in \mathbb{C}$ then we can write $z=|z|(\cos \theta +i\sin \theta)$ this representation recives the name of polar form of the complex number.

Exists a theorem that speak about the roots of some complex number and say that the $n$-th roots of the number $z$ above are given by

$$w_k=|z|^{1/n}\left( \cos \left(\frac{\theta+2\pi k}{n}\right)+i \sin \left(\frac{\theta+2\pi k}{n}\right) \right)$$

and where $k=0,1,2,3\cdots n-1$

One example for this  get the roots of $z=1+0i$ notice that $\theta=0$ and $|z|=1$ and we want $\sqrt[3]{z}$.

The theorem say

$$w_k=|z|^{1/n}\left( \cos \left(\frac{\theta+2\pi k}{n}\right)+i \sin \left(\frac{\theta+2\pi k}{n}\right) \right)$$

Applying the theorem

$$w_0=1\left( \cos \left(\frac{0}{3}\right)+i \sin \left(\frac{0}{3}\right) \right)=1+0i$$
$$w_{1}=\left( \cos \left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)+i \sin \left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right) \right)=\frac{-1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
$$w_{3}=\left( \cos \left(\frac{4\pi}{3}\right)+i \sin \left(\frac{4\pi}{3}\right) \right)=\frac{-1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Notice that the values of the binomial form are get from the value of $\cos(\text{angle})$ for the real part and $\sin\text{angle}$ for the imaginary part.

I wait that you can apply the theorem from here

**Hint**:
In your case $z=0-8i$ and $\theta=\frac{3 \pi}{2}$, $|z|=8, n=3, k=0,1,2$

Answer (score 0):

You can also return to the equivalent polynomial problem, since it is clear what one of the roots is:

$$ z^3 \ + \ 8i \ \ = \ \ (z \ - \ 2i ) \ · \ (z^2 \ + \ 2i z \ + \ [2i]^2)  \ \ = \ \ (z \ - \ 2i ) \ · \ (z^2 \ + \ 2i z \ - \ 4) \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ . $$

The other two roots are given by

$$ z \ \ = \ \ \frac{-2i \ \pm \ \sqrt{[2i]^2 \ -  \ 4 · 1 · (-4)}}{2} \ \ = \ \  \frac{-2i \ \pm \ \sqrt{(-4) \ +  \ 16}}{2} \ \ = \ \ -i \ \pm \ \sqrt{3} \ \ . $$

(This one works out without needing to know how square-roots of complex numbers are found.)